# The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) long, Object

Tags: java

I'm working on a simple java app which calculates different request times. I'm getting the error, The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) long, Object for

```
  for (int requestTime : requests) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){

            -redacted-
                }
            }
        }, time - System.currentTimeMillis() - (long)latency - (Object)requestTime);
    }
```

I was wondering if anybody could help me solve my little problem.
Happy new year.

Comment: What's the type of `requestTime`?

Comment: What do you expect should happen when you apply the operator `-` on a long value?

Comment: What is the value of 42 - banana? Or 37 - socket?

Comment: I've updated my code, sorry for the problem.

Comment: `requestTime` is an `Object` since you've explicitly casted it as such. How do you expect to subtract a long from an Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` operator, as the error message says, is undefined between a `long` and an `Object`. Just drop the cast and you should be fine:

```
time - System.currentTimeMillis() - (long)latency - requestTime
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It worked perfectly. Have a good night.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting `requestTime` to a generic Object before you attempt math on it. That doesn't make any sense.

Just don't cast it to an Object, since generic objects don't have support for `-`. If you intended to wrap the `int`, use

```
Integer(requestTime);
```

instead.